# Ruby on Rails getting HTTP 500 with no error logged (hosted on Media Temple)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mongrel, mediatemple

I am trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails application on Media Temple. The application starts fine (Mongrel starts up fine) but I keep on getting a HTTP 500 error.

The problem is that nothing gets written to the log, so I do now know what might be causing this problem.

I have 256M of memory available so I do not believe memory is an issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the the problem was solved by moving to another host. Not the ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to make sure that the "mongrel user" has the ability to write to the tmp/, log/

Answer (score 1):

It may be an Apache error related to proxying requests to your mongrel. Check the Apache log as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try seeing the steps given above, But as a practice or a convenience, use Hoptoad Notifier or Exception Notifier to your Rails Application.

Its a nice way to keeping track of exceptions in your Rails app and you get email notifications with all the necessary details.

Answer (score 1):

You could have started a script/server session running on Mongrel, that way the logs get printed directly in the session.

But I guess it's fixed either way now ;-)